# set the Django's model to a specific day in a month?

Tags: django, model, datefield

I have a monthly report model and I want to set it to a specific date (cycle).
This is my model:

```
class MonthlyReport(m.Model):
    month  = m.DateField()  <=   set to a specific day in a month
    worker = m.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    total  = m.IntegerField()
    cycle  = m.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    approvedDate = m.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: are you asking to set a default or do that when creating a new object?

Answer (score 0):

you could set [`auto_now=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) so it is set to actual date once object is updated:

```
month  = m.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

your model is just a definition of a report class. the specific month will be set to its object once the report object is created/updated in that specific month.

```
may_report = MonthlyReport(worker=some_user, total=23, .....)
may_report.save()
```

`month` field is automatically updated with actual month's date.  you dont need to do anything for it.